# setinterval $_GET["variable"] return empty

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I'm using setInterval like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ $('div#data').load('./data.php').fadeIn("fast"); },1000);
```

The url is something like this: `localhost/test.php?data=ok`

In data.php, I get variable from $_GET:

```
$data = $_GET["data"];
```

When the document is ready `$data` has the value `ok`, but when the interval loads, `$data` has lost its value..

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out 100% works

test.html =>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: "GET",
            data: "data=ok",
            cache: true,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);           
            }
            });
    },1000);
});
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

test.php =>

```
<?php echo $_GET['data']; ?>
```

now open console of your browser and you see 'ok' in response

Comment: thx brother, but the bug is already fixed by me... thx for share..!

Answer (score 3):

Because HTTP is a **stateless** protocol. Every request isn't related to another request in any way. And for each HTTP request new environment for php script is created from the scratch. So, the second request doesn't have `?data=ok` thus server knows nothing about `$_GET["data"]`

Comment: well, how to make it.. `?data=ok`

Comment: @Jin Sun: pass it ;-) `load('./data.php?data=ok')`

Comment: @Jin Sun: use firebug and see what actually is passed

Comment: i am using chrome, well i think it just a little problem, but i dont know where is th matter..

Comment: @Jin Sun: "yes" what? What do you see on Networks? Do you see the variable is passed?

Comment: @Jin Sun: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're talking about

Comment: it is strange, when i create simulation with simple code, it is work...
but it is not work in my original code..

Comment: @Jin Sun: so get F12 and debug ;-)

Comment: i found the bug!!! if i used `?data=ok sir` it will return empty... thx brother for sharing!